# Problemas com o módulo gm (GraphicsMagick) e node.js

Tags: node.js

Estou fazendo um projeto teste para ver as funcionalidades do módulo gm, pois preciso manipular imagens no servidor (redimensionar, colocar *watermark*, gerar *thumb*, entre outros).

Pois bem, instalei o GraphicsMagick via Homebrew usando o comando

```
brew install GraphicsMagick
```

E a instalação rolou ok.

Instalei o módulo no projeto via npm usando

```
npm install gm --save
```

Estou usando express, e no meu *route* usei o seguinte código

```
exports.tamanho = function(req, res){

gm('./images/1.jpg').size(function(err, value){
  if(err) res.json(500, {message: err});
  res.json(200, {messagem: value});
});}
```

Fazendo o devido require no topo usando `var gm = require('gm');`

Este código está retornando para mim um erro que não consegui identificar

`{message:{"code": null,signal": "SIGTRAP"}}`

Alguém que já teve algum problema parecido sabe o que pode ser, se consegue resolver ou se tem algum outro módulo bom de usar para as tarefas que preciso?

Comment: O que faz esse método `size`? Não achei na [documentação do gm](http://aheckmann.github.io/gm/docs.html).

Comment: http://aheckmann.github.io/gm/docs.html#getters   
Coloquei ele apenas para testar...mas tenho um de recortar que dá o mesmo erro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvi removendo o ImageMagick que estava instalado e o GraphicsMagick. 
Reinstalei apenas o GraphicsMagick e funcionou.